# C/C++ Is it possible to #undef a serial of macro starting by the same patern?

Tags: macros, c-preprocessor

I'm writing a tool using macros to generate enum. When done, I want to undef all those macros, but I don't know all names yet. Somes will comes later in developement. So I want to make a generic undef like...

```
#undef ENUM_*
```

Is that possible ? The macros simplified looks like that:

First...

```
#define ENUM_VALUE(VALUE) VALUE,
#define ENUM_STRING(STRING) #STRING,

#define ENUM_GENERATE(NAME)\
    namespace NAME {\
        enum Enum: int { ENUM_##NAME(ENUM_VALUE) };\
        const char *Names[] = { ENUM_##NAME(ENUM_STRING) };\
    }\
```

Then for each enum I define...

```
#define ENUM_MyEnum(VALUE)\
    VALUE(Value1)\
    VALUE(Value2)\
    VALUE(Value3)

ENUM_GENERATE(MyEnum)
```

It generate a synchronized enum and string table like if I had declared

```
namespace MyEnum { 
    enum Enum: int { Value1, Value2, Value3 };
    const char *Names[] = { "Value1", "Value2", "Value3" };
}
```

The only problem is that I end with truck load of macros. Somes I don't know yet, because they will be define later when I new enums will be creted. But all start by ENUM_

Is there a simple way to undef them all ? Thanks

Comment: Did you read the documentation? What **specifically** is unclear about 6.10.3.5p1 in the C standard? And the expansion code is not C.

Comment: Note: the macros don't seem to do something reasonable and the whole approach is broken by design, ending in macro hell without any benefit. Don't get too fancy with macros, especially in C++ you mostly can (and should) use core-language constructs. Macros complicate debugging and `undef`ing (and possibly redefining) macros arbitrarily makes things even worse.

Comment: No, I do not know the documentation you talk about. Do you have a link on it ?

Comment: About the macro, I know it's not a good tool. However, they allow to make a synchronized system, and this is important to me. Template do not.

Comment: What is "a synchronised system" in that sense? To be clear: If a co-worker would provided such code in one of my projects, we'd hav a very serious talk about his qualifications.

Comment: I can imagine... but I didn't decribed the case. It's a litle long... I'm writing a tool that use communication, and since it can be tricky to debug, I have build a "blackbox" that record everything everywhere. Including the enum values. I need that those debug purpose functions output informations about my enums. And I need it to be as automatic and as transparent as possible, because I don't want to waste too much time just setting blackbox stuffs or polute too much my source code. So I use macro - yes, the evil. stuff - it work very well, indeed.

Comment: As I suspected: this is an XY problem. You use the wrong approach and now ask how to fix it. I don't support marcos being "evil" in general. They have their use. However, this is not the correct way (and it ist still unclear why you want to `undef` the macros).

Comment: Indeed, this is an XY problem.  I'm guessing the problem you really want to solve is "how do I do X Macros properly", but merely by my mentioning the name you can probably find out now on your own.

Comment: @Olaf, Sorry, I didn't make myself clear. My macros work very well and there is nothing to fix. They allow me to replace an horrible stuff, very hard to maintain, and I know why I use them. I'm happy with that. But it could be better if I undef after use, just to cleanup. That's all.

Comment: @H Walters, yes, I found a way to undef and cleanup. I'm not used to macros, so I was looking for infos. A generic undef would be cool, but I can manage without it. Thanks.

Comment: Would you be interested in a solution which leaves some defined macros behind, but guarantees that any use is blocked by a single macro not being defined? I.e. you undef that single one and all attempts to use one of the macros from the group it represents result in a "undefined" error.

Comment: Sounds cool. I didn't think it this way, but you are true. This is a solution and it's rather easy to implement. I only have to use a base macro in each of the next one. Then, undefine the base macro... and I'll get an error if an invalid call is done. Thank you.

Comment: @Yunnosch   I am very interested.

Comment: @javaLover Thanks for the feedback. I made an answer. Also thanks for making me see this, I did not notice OPs indication of being interested.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a detailed proposal for the "base macro" idea from comment:
It leaves some defined macros behind, but guarantees that any use is blocked by a single macro not being defined.
I.e. you undef that single one and all attempts to use one of the macros from the group it represents result in a "undefined" error,
or maybe in some defined expansion, which is however sure to annoy the compiler.

```
// Infrastructure
#define BASE_BASE(ParWhich) BASED_##ParWhich

// Secondary infrastructure, needed for supporting parameterised macros.
#define BASE_NOPAR(ParWhich) BASE_BASE(ParWhich)
#define BASE_ONEPAR(ParWhich, ParOne) BASE_BASE(ParWhich)(ParOne)

// Potentially many macros being defined in a slightly "get-used-to" manner.
#define BASED_A Hello
#define BASED_B(ParWhat) ParWhat
#define BASED_C(ParWord) ParWord

// Example line, to be expanded by prepro with defined macro BASE_BASE.
BASE_NOPAR(A) BASE_ONEPAR(B,PreProcessor) BASE_NOPAR(B)(World.)


// The one line which should lead to compiler errors for any use of one of the macros.
#undef BASE_BASE

// Same example again.
BASE_NOPAR(A) BASE_ONEPAR(B,PreProcessor) BASE_NOPAR(B)(World.)

// Not necessary, just to make sure and to make readable prepro-output.
#define BASE_BASE(ParIgnore) Compiler, please fail here!

// Same example again.
BASE_NOPAR(A) BASE_ONEPAR(B,PreProcessor) BASE_NOPAR(B)(World.)
```

Using the parameter-free base macro with a parameter in a following pair braces, as done in the example `BASE_NOPAR(C)(World.)`
should not be done directly in code anywhere; because it would, in my opinion,
turn into maintenance nightmare soon.
I.e. it should be done in a central "core" place as demonstrated otherwise.
Wouldn't want any code written like that.

Output:

```
>gcc -E -P BaseMacro.c
Hello PreProcessor World.
BASE_BASE(A) BASE_BASE(B)(PreProcessor) BASE_BASE(B)(World.)
Compiler, please fail here! Compiler, please fail here!(PreProcessor) Compiler, please fail here!(World.) Compiler, please fail here!(World.)
```

Comment: Note: The example is not designed to be compileable, it is for demonstrating the concept, seen through preprocessing-only run of compiler, as shown in output.

Comment: I can grasp the idea.  `BASE_BASE` is a bridge, and the bridge is destroyed (`undef`) at the end. ..... The usage is not so intuitive, but it is an interesting idea.  Thank.